# How to know when Neo4j is ready to serve

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

I've developed an application which connects to Neo4j and creates a bunch of nodes. I've also developed a plugin for Neo4j using Graphaware. And both these are run in separate dockers (one for the code and one for the Neo4j with plugin).

Now, since I start these containers automatically and simultaneously, the code should wait for the Neo4j to completely start before it tries creating the nodes. For that, I'm testing the availability of the Neo4j by trying to connect to it using bolt protocol (Neo4j's driver).

The problem I've got is that it seems Neo4j starts accepting incoming connections before it completely loads the plugins. As the result, the connection is made before Neo4j is actually prepared and also something goes wrong (I don't know what) and the whole code halts (I don't think this issue is important) all because the connection is made before the plugins are loaded. I know that since if I delay the connection manually, everything goes forward smoothly.

So my question is how to make sure that Neo4j is warmed up (fully) before starting to connect to it? Right now I'm checking the availability of management (http://localhost:7474) but what if there's no management, to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you'll find that you can keep the management interface local, but you can't actually turn it off (unless you're working in embedded mode), so waiting for http://localhost:7474 is a good approach. If you want to be more fine-grained, you can check **yourinstallation**\logs\debug.log

```
2017-07-27 03:58:53.643+0000 INFO [o.n.k.AvailabilityGuard] Fulfilling of requirement makes database available: Database available
2017-07-27 03:58:53.644+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Database is now ready
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom